# How to make Cygwin the default shell for Jenkins?

Tags: build, jenkins, cygwin, scons

I'm trying to come up with some sensible solution for a build written using SCons, which relies on quite a lot of applications to be accessible in a Unix-like way, using Unix-like paths etc. However, when I'm trying to use SCons plugin, or Git plugin in Jenkins, it tries to invoke the plugins using something like `cmd /c git.exe` - and this will certainly fail, because Git was installed using Cygwin and is only known in Cygwin shell, but not in CMD. But even if I could make git and the rest available to cmd.exe, other problems arise: the Cygwin version of Git expects paths to have forward slashes and treats backward slashes as escape characters. Idiotic Windows file-system related issues kick in too (I can't give Jenkins permissions to delete my own files!).

So, is there a way to somehow make Jenkins only use Cygwin shell, and never cmd.exe? Or should I be prepared to run some Linux in a VM to have this handled?

Answer (score 2):

You could configure Jenkins to execute the cygwin command with the specific shell command, as follows:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\mintty --hold always --exec /cygdrive/c/path/to/bash/script.sh
```

Where `script.sh` will execute all the commands needed for the Jenkins execution.

Comment: This doesn't really help because the plugins such as Git plugin or SCons decide somehow to use `cmd.exe`. I was hoping they make this decision based on some Jenkin's internal settings - after all they should be able to act as if they were in Unix environment...

Comment: OK, I've tried this and there are several problems with this approach... 1. Output from Cygwin isn't sent to "console output" in Jenkins. 2. What exactly does `--hold always` do? If I keep this option, the build never finishes (Cygwin never exits), if I remove it - the build exits immediately, not doing anything...

Comment: Here is the mintty manpage: http://mintty.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.1/docs/mintty.1.html Use "-l -" to output to stdout.

Comment: Thanks for ongoing help. There appeared to be another issue (you aren't to blame for it). Jenkins runs with SYSTEM user permissions, and when it calls Cygwin being that idiotic user, things go awry :( Words can't express how much I hate Windows user policies, but this one is extra bad. It just seems like it'll never work with any program on that PC. I will probably need to find a way to run Jenkins as my normal user - that being done, I've figured I can just call `c:\cygwin\bin\bash` to get what I need.

Comment: You can set Jenkins to run as any user if you open the Jenkins service on Windows. I set it to run as my primary user so I have more control.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record here's what I ended up doing:

1. Added a user `SYSTEM` to Cygwin, `mkpasswd -u SYSTEM`
2. Edited `/etc/passwd` by adding the newly created user's home directory to the record. Now it looks something like the below:

   SYSTEM:*:18:544:,S-1-5-18:/home/SYSTEM:
3. Copied my own user's configuration settings such as `.netrc`, `.ssh` and so on into the `SYSTEM` home. Then, from Windows Explorer, through an array of popups I've claimed ownership of all of these files to `SYSTEM` user. One by one! I love Microsoft!
   In Jenkins I now run a wrapper for my build that sets some other environment variables etc. by calling `c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i /path/to/script/script`
4. Gave it up because of other difficulties in configuration and made Jenkins service run under my user rather then `SYSTEM`. Here's a blog post on how to do it: http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html but, basically, you need to open Windows services, then find Jenkins service, select it's properties, go to "Logon" tab and change the user to the "this user".

Comment: Thanks for this insight, I am in the same hell right now.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to start your "execute shell" build steps with

```
#!c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login
```

The trick is of course that it resets your current directory so you need to

```
cd `cygpath $WORKSPACE`
```

to get back to the workspace.

Comment: And it does not work for the initial checkout, of course. Still trying to figure out how to make Jenkins use a Cygwin git...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to thon56's good answer: this is helpful: "set -ex"

```
#!c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login 
cd `cygpath $WORKSPACE`
set -ex
```

Details:

- -e to exit on error. This is important if you want your jobs to fail on error.
- -x to echo command to the screen, if desired.

You can also use #!c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -ex, but that echos a lot of login steps that you most likely don't care to see.

Answer (score 0):

To run sh in Jenkins windows, follow these steps:

1. Install Cygwin in the C drive
2. Go to manage Jenkins> system > shell then mention here path of Cygwin, `C:\cygwin64\bin`
3. Go to manage Jenkins > available plugins > Cygpath install and restart Jenkins
4. Create a new job/item > build steps> execute shell> Start writing shell with shebang `#!/bin/sh`